# Issues integrating java client application with Salesforce (wsc API)

Tags: java, salesforce, sslhandshakeexception, wsc

I had to connect to salesforce through my Java application and followed the steps provided by [salesforce.com Introduction](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector). I faced a couple of issues in this process and any help would really help me a lot.

- **Issue 1:** First and foremeost I am unable to build `wsc.jar` after cloning the project from GIT. The project gives a compilation error when imported in `myeclipse` when compiler version is 1.6. There were no errors if I change the compiler version to 1.7.
- **Issue 2:** Instead of building jar file , I downloaded `wsc-20.jar` from an online resource (link provided in comments below) and generated `enterprise.jar` from the WSDL given to me by a salesforce developer. I included `wsc-23.jar` and `enterprise.jar` in my project buildpath and implemented the code as provided by salesforce(link provided below). When I run the code, a runtime exception is encountered as below and the request failed to sent to `test.salesforce.com`. The exception and error log are provided below.

After certain investigation, I found out that the API libraries and the Java code are working perfectly fine when Java JRE version is switched to 1.7. But somehow this isn't working in 1.6 environment and I get the below error and I cannot upgrade my project's Java version to 1.7.

Runtime Exception:

> com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/36.0/
>          at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:129)
>          at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection.login(EnterpriseConnection.java:1)
>          at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection.(EnterpriseConnection.java:1)
>          at com.nsf.ecap.web.business.proposal.SalesforceLoginTest.main(SalesforceLoginTest.java:27)
>   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>          at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
>          at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1611)
>          at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:187)
>          at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:181)
>          at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1035)
>          at [1]com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:124)
>          at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
>          at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Not sure if it is exactly related, but Salesforce recently changed their public certificate, causing some integration to fail. Check if you got the latest one. Also check if you got correct root and intermediate certificates.

Comment: I am using wsc-20.jar which is compatabile with java 1.6 from the link provided https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/sfdc-wsc/wsc-20.jar .. But still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Upon further debug and analyzing weblogic logs, it was identified as an SSL related issue.  The issue was resolved when 'BEA Hostname Verifier' property is set to false in Weblogic server.

Below are the links for more information regarding SSL troubleshooting and setting hostname verifier property in weblogic.

https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/ssl-troubleshooting-and-debugging

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E72987_01/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/security/VerifyHostNameVerification.html